# Oracle code to find related IDs associated with one person

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table of patients on medical insurance policy where one patient can be on more than 1 policy , the common link to identify those patients is the column called "Related Patient ID' . I need to identify those partients from my database who have got product type A and B both

Here is the sample data:

```
Person ID   Patient ID  Related Patient ID  Product Person name
23137710    31989323    31992056    A   Liam
23139357    31992056    31989323    B   Liam
12123333    32321543    76767666    A   Tracy
12436654    76767666    32321543    B   Tracy
```

Comment: Only two products, or could be more?

Comment: Just two products

Answer (score 1):

If there are only two products I would use:

```
select
    a.patient_id as id1,
    b.patient_id as id2,
    a.person_name
  from my_table a
  join my_table b on a.patient_id = b.related_patient_id
                 and b.patient_id = a.related_patient_id
                 and a.product <> b.product
                 and a.patient_id < b.patient_id
```